# Good way to identify the code section in /proc/*/maps

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I'm trying to find the address range that my native Android library's **code** occupies in the process' address space. I'm reading and parsing `/proc/self/maps`. There are two sections for the library. One is code, the other one is data, I presume. I need to tell them apart. However, the difference between them is, well, kinda circumstantial. Testing on Android 2.3.3.

The code section's permissions are r-xp, the data's are rwxp - both are executable. I feel uneasy basing the decision upon writeability - what if on same flavors of Android, there's a read-only data section?

The other difference is offset of the mapped section relative to the file - the code section has offset 0. Again, what if some iteration of the linker places data before code?

The tools, like GDB and Android's stack walker, have no problem telling me what module does a code address belong to, and what's its offset in the library. Just sayin'.

EDIT: on Android 4.0, the sections are different: there's r-xp, r--p, rw-p. So that lets me identify the executable section failry easily - but what about earlier Androids?

Comment: mine doesn't have executable flag on both code and data.

Comment: Probably different Android version...

Comment: I think it is fair to check on 'x' flag.

Comment: Won't be compatible with Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. Fortunately, those are **my** libraries, so I can get a address that's for sure within the code block by having a function that returns its own address. Then I match it against section boundaries.

```
void *TestAddress()
{
    return TestAddress; //That's within the code block, that's for sure.
}
```

This won't work for third party libraries, because a function address of an imported function would correspond to the import thunk, not to the real function's body.